# Finding the number of distinct sequences of length 10, with 5 consecutive 1s or 0s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find the number of distinct 10-length sequences that contain at least 5 consecutive 1s or 0s.

My thoughts: For precisely 5 consecutive 1s, we have:
111110xxxx
0111110xxx
x0111110xx
xx0111110x
xxx0111110
xxxx011111

(where X can be either 1 or 0). There are $2^4+2^3+2^3+2^3+2^3+2^4 = 64$ combinations.

For 6 consecutive 1s:
1111110xxx
01111110xx
x01111110x
xx0111111x
xxx0111111

Total = 32

For 7 1s:
11111110xx
011111110x
x011111110
xx01111111

Total combinations = 12

For 8 1s:
111111110x
0111111110
x011111111

Total combinations = 5

For 9 1s:
1111111110
0111111111

Total combinations = 2

For 10 1s:

Total combinations = 1

If we add up all the combinations, we get 116 combinations. Now, we can A or B with at least 5 consecutive occurrences, so we multiply this by 2 to give 232.

However, the actual answer is 222, and I don't know why my method isn't working.

Comment: Suppose you have a sequence $111110xxxx$ but the $xxxx$ part actually runs $0000$  You have double counted those, and need to exclude the cases with two sequences in them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xx0111111x` in "6 consecutive" should be `xx01111110`, changing your calculation

An alternative approach

```
11111xxxxx  32 ways
011111xxxx  16 ways
x011111xxx  16 ways
xx011111xx  16 ways
xxx011111x  16 ways
xxxx011111  16 ways
```

$32+5\times 16 = 112$. Double to give $224$ and subtract $2$ because `0000011111` and `1111100000`are double counted

Answer (score 0):

Your six consecutive should give $8+4+4+4+8=28$, not $32$, so that reduces your count to $112$.  Doubling that for five zeros gets you to $224$.  Then you have double counted $0000011111$ and $1111100000$ because you counted them once for the five ones and once for the five zeros, so subtract two.  That gives $222$.